# List View onClick passing _id

Tags: android, listview

I have created a List view of all the Inbox emails of a user. Now on clicking the email id. I wanna have an activity where i display the content of the mail. Problem is i am not able to understand how to pass the ID of the mail to the activity to fetch that Email with Details.

```
public class InboxActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inbox);

        DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(InboxActivity.this);
        db.open();
        long userID = Long.parseLong(MessagingApplication.getUserID());

        Cursor inbox = db.readInbox(userID);
        startManagingCursor(inbox);

        String[] mails = new String[] { DBAdapter.KEY_SUB };

        int[] to = new int[] { R.id.subject };

        SimpleCursorAdapter inboxmail = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                R.layout.inbox_list, inbox, mails, to);

        setListAdapter(inboxmail);

        db.close();
    }
}
```

This is  my Inbox as List View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Android SDK Notebook example](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/src/com/example/android/notepad/NotesList.html).
You'll see there that they are using an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to **pass data around** (data in your case being URIs pointing to your mails).

You can have something like the code below to construct a mailUri (based on the selected item in your list), and **start a new activity by passing on a new intent** containing an **Action** (Intent.ACTION_VIEW) and **Data** (mailUri).

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Uri mailUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(getIntent().getData(), id);
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, mailUri));
}
```

Using Itents makes your code more loosely coupled and promotes re-use (notice how you don't specify the activity name that needs to be started).

Check the android fundamentals on [Intent Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#ifilters) to see how you can **configure** an activity to act upon your ACTION_VIEW mailUri.